# redis-server doesn't start on a fresh debian 10 installation

Tags: redis, debian

I am preparing a new Debian 10 vps. I've 2 cpus, 8 GB of RAM.

I installed redis-server and simply configured 'require-pass' in `/etc/redis/redis.conf`.

I am trying to start but I got every time this

```
 sudo  /etc/init.d/redis-server start
[....] Starting redis-server (via systemctl): redis-server.serviceJob for redis-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status redis-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

The status give me no infos

```
systemctl status redis-server.service
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-07-17 15:30:45 UTC; 16s ago
     Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
           man:redis-server(1)
  Process: 18678 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dyamer@localhost:/etc$
```

What could it be? How to diagnose and fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn, the problem was a quote in the password.

Removed
Fixed